# ID and connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my administrator panel, I have 2 Roles, `admin` and `former`:

[image]

For now, I have 3 users:

- the first role is admin, the pseudo is admin and email address is admin@gmail.com
- the second role is former, it has like pseudo Remace and email address is test@gmail.com
- the third user is always a former, it has like pseudo Gofette and email address is ledeluge1990@gmail.com

[image]

For information, the administrator is the only one to create records.

Here, I have 2 recordings: (It's the informations of the formers)

[image]

Now, my goal is that each former has access to his informations.

So, the first former is Remace with email adresse test@gmail.com.

I log in with email adresse of Remace ( test@gmail.com )

I see this :

[image]

In fact, I retrieve the informations of Gofette and not those of Remace, why ???

Now, I want to connect with the user Gofette with email adresse ledeluge1990@gmail.com...

I see nothing ???

[image]

I think my problem is in my function index() ????

```
public function index()
    {   

        if($has_role = auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')){
            $garages = Garage::oldest()->paginate(5);
            return view('admin.garages.index', compact('garages'));
        } else{
            $garages = Garage::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);
            return view('admin.garages.index', compact('garages'));
        }

    }


   public function create()
    {

        $localites = Localite::all();
        return view('admin.garages.create', compact('localites', 'garages'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {      


        $request->validate([
           'nom' => 'required|string|max:25|min:3|alpha',
            'adresse' => 'required|string|max:50|min:12',
            'fk_localite' => 'required',
            'telephone' => 'required|string|min:8|max:11',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:25|min:10'


         ]);

        $exists = Garage::where('nom', $request->get('nom'))->where('adresse', $request->get('adresse'))->where('fk_localite', $request->get('fk_localite'))->where('telephone', $request->get('telephone'))->where('email', $request->get('email'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Garage::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('garages.index')
                ->with('success', 'Un nouvel enregistrement a été effectué');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('garages.index')
                ->with('error', 'Doublon, cet enregistrement existe déjà! ');

        } 

    }
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This line is likely incorrect `$garages = Garage::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);`. It's searching for `Garage` records with an `id` matching the user's `id`.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter: Thank you for your answer, do you have any idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the comment above your `$garages = Garage::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);`. It's searching for Garage records with an `id` matching the user's `id`.

To solve this problem, you can :

1. Change the query to : `$garages = Garage::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->paginate(5);`
2. Or create another `user_id` field in garages table to assign each of the former to their garages.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, my problem is now solve. I was stuck for 2 days.